# What is the best way to get sum of array values for each unique combination of values from three other arrays?

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I am working with geospatial raster data and want to know the area covered by each unique combination from a set of 2D arrays. My target is a  `m x n x o, ...` `DataArray` where `m`, `n`, and `o` are the number of unique levels of each input array.

My solution involves converting the 2D arrays into a set of coordinates, then re-indexing the weights array on the new coordinates, but this seems to load all of the data into memory so I wonder if there is a more dask-y way to solve this problem.

This feels like a problem that should have a simple and fast solution - I would love to hear your ideas!

Here is some toy data:

```py
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# shape of x, y dimensions
shape = (1024, 1024)

# three layers with random integer values
layers = {
    layer: xr.DataArray(
        data=da.from_array((scale * np.random.rand(*shape)).astype(int)),
        dims=["x", "y"],
        coords=[np.arange(i) for i in shape],
    ) for layer, scale in zip(["a", "b", "c"], [4, 8, 2])
}

# combined into a 3 x 1024 x 1024 DataArray
layered = xr.concat(
    [arr.assign_coords(layer=layer) for layer, arr in layers.items()],
    dim="layer"
)

# array of weights for each pixel representing the area of each cell
weights = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.ones_like(layers["c"].data),
    dims=["x", "y"],
    coords=[np.arange(i) for i in shape],
)
```

Here is the simplest solution that I have found:

```py
# define a new set of dictionary of coordinates with the array values indexed on `x` and `y`
coords = {
    key: (("y", "x"), arr.data)
    for key, arr in layers.items())
}

# add these coordinates to the weights array
weights = weights.assign_coords(coords=coords)

# stack x and y dimensions to make it possible to reindex on the new coordinates (has to be 1-D)
stacked = weights.stack(cats=["x", "y"])

# reindex the array on the new coordinates (maybe this is loading all data into memory?)
reindexed = stacked.set_xindex(coord_names=list(coords.keys()))

# get sum by group
summed = (
    reindexed
    .groupby("cats")
    .sum()
    .unstack()
)
```

It works, but I am hoping to find a solution that does not require re-indexing.

I also worked out a solution using `numpy.bincount` but it is slower than the xarray-based approach:

```py
# get unique combinations using np.unique
layered_stacked = layered.stack(xy=["x", "y"])
classified, unique_idxs = np.unique(
    layered_stacked, axis=1, return_inverse=True, equal_nan=True
)

# set unique indexes in as values in the array
stacked_unique = layered_stacked.isel(layer=0)
stacked_unique.data = unique_idxs

# use np.bincount with weights to get sum by each unique index
index_sums = np.bincount(
    stacked_unique,
    weights=weights.stack(cats=["x", "y"])
)

# fill out the new DataArray
out_coords = {
    layer: np.unique(classified[i, ])
    for layer, i in zip(layers.keys(), range(classified.shape[0]))
}

out_array = np.zeros(shape=[len(arr) for arr in out_coords.values()])

for i, index_sum in enumerate(index_sums):
    _coords = classified[:, i]
    arr_idx = []
    for val, coord_set in zip(_coords, out_coords.values()):
        if np.isnan(val):
            match = np.where(np.isnan(coord_set))[0]
        else:
            match = np.where(coord_set == val)[0]
        
        arr_idx.append(int(match))
    out_array[tuple(arr_idx)] = index_sum

summed_numpy = xr.DataArray(
    data=out_array,
    dims=layers,
    coords={layer: out_coords[layer] for layer in layers},
)
```